# How to connect controller eloquent's

Tags: laravel

I don't know if my question title is correct but I will try to form the question here correctly.

So I am creating order and customer management system in laravel and I am struggling with connecting two tables and controllers with each other.

I have two tables:

[orders table with one test record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPXsn.png)

[customers table with one test record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K94zK.png)

Also I have controller "OrdersController" with store function here is a source code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request, [
        'customer'=>'required',
        'date'=>'required',
        'products'=>'required',
        'phone'=>'required',
        'country'=>'required',
        'state'=>'required',
        'city'=>'required',
        'address1'=>'required',
        'address2'=>'required',
        'zip'=>'required',
        'sold_price'=>'required',
        'gross_price'=>'required',
        'paypal_fee'=>'required',
        'track_number'=>'required',
        'track_price'=>'required',
        'track_link'=>'required',
        'currency'=>'required'
    ]);

    $order = new Order;
    $order->customer = $request->input('customer');
    $order->date = $request->input('date');
    $order->products = $request->input('products');
    $order->phone = $request->input('phone');
    $order->country = $request->input('country');
    $order->state = $request->input('state');
    $order->city = $request->input('city');
    $order->address1 = $request->input('address1');
    $order->address2 = $request->input('address2');
    $order->zip = $request->input('zip');
    $order->sold_price = $request->input('sold_price');
    $order->gross_price = $request->input('gross_price');
    $order->paypal_fee = $request->input('paypal_fee');
    $order->track_number = $request->input('track_number');
    $order->track_price = $request->input('track_price');
    $order->track_link = $request->input('track_link');
    $order->currency = $request->input('currency');
    $order->save();

    return redirect('/orders')->with('success', 'შეკვეთა წარმატებით დაემატა');
}
```

So I want to check if record with $order->phone exists in customers table, if it exists don't create new record in customers table, and if it not exists I want to create new record in customers table with $order->customer (customer's name) and $order->phone (customer's phone).

This is my questions, I am a beginner and this is my first project, if here is some fatal mistakes please tell me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check in customer table with phone number record exist or not like this. I assume that your customer model is Customer

```
$customer = Customer::where('phone', '=', $request->input('phone'))->first();
if(!$customer){
  create Customer here
}

$order = new Order;
$order->customer = $request->input('customer');
$order->date = $request->input('date');
$order->products = $request->input('products');
$order->phone = $request->input('phone');
$order->country = $request->input('country');
$order->state = $request->input('state');
$order->city = $request->input('city');
$order->address1 = $request->input('address1');
$order->address2 = $request->input('address2');
$order->zip = $request->input('zip');
$order->sold_price = $request->input('sold_price');
$order->gross_price = $request->input('gross_price');
$order->paypal_fee = $request->input('paypal_fee');
$order->track_number = $request->input('track_number');
$order->track_price = $request->input('track_price');
$order->track_link = $request->input('track_link');
$order->currency = $request->input('currency');
$order->save();

return redirect('/orders')->with('success', 'შეკვეთა წარმატებით დაემატა');
```